# Prove trigonometric identity $\frac{\sin^6x}{1 - \tan^2x} + \frac{\cos^6x}{1-\cot^2x} = - \sin^2x \cdot \cos^2x$

Tags: trigonometry

I've got this task,

$$\frac{\sin^6x}{1 - \tan^2x} + \frac{\cos^6x}{1-\cot^2x} = - \sin^2x \cdot \cos^2x$$

I've gotten to this part but I'm not even sure it's the correct path to take since if i actually add the two fractions i get even worse situation with nothing to remove.

$$\frac{\sin^6x \cdot \cos^2x}{\cos^2x - \sin^2x} + \frac{\cos^6x \cdot \sin^2x}{\sin^2x - \cos^2x} = - \sin^2x \cdot \cos^2x$$

Thanks

Comment: What is $ctg^2$?

Comment: You have made substantial progress, and are in fact quite close to the end. Bring to a common denominator, that's just a sign change. and now factor the top.

Comment: $ctg^2 = 1/tg^2$

Comment: @AndréNicolas okay will try. Thanks

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: @pbs uhh can you tell me which rule is used by doing that please?

Comment: As it is written, the left-hand side is undefined for (for example) $x=\pi/4$, but the right-hand side is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost have it: factor  out $\sin^2x\cos^2x$ from the numerator
\begin{align*}
\frac{\sin^6x\cos^2x}{\cos^2x-\sin^2x}&+\frac{\cos^6x\sin^2x}{\sin^2x-\cos^2x}=
-\sin^2x\cos^2x\frac{\cos^4x-\sin4x}{\cos^2x-\sin^2x}\\
&=-\sin^2x\cos^2x\frac{\cos^2x-\sin2x}{\cos^2x-\sin^2x}=-\sin^2x\cos^2x.
\end{align*}

Comment: How did you get $cos^4x - sin^4x$ to be $cos^2x - sin^2x$ in step 2->3

Comment: $A^4-B^4=(A^2-B^2)(A^2+B^2)$, and $A^2+B^2=\dots$

Comment: You're welcome. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{\sin^6x \cdot \cos^2x}{\cos^2x - \sin^2x} + \frac{\cos^6x \cdot \sin^2x}{\sin^2x - \cos^2x} = - \sin^2x \cdot \cos^2x$$
Multiply by $\sin^2x-\cos^2x$ to get

$$-\sin^6x\cos^2x+\cos^6x\sin^2x=-\sin^2x\cos^2x(\sin^2x - \cos^2x)$$

Expand

$$-\sin^6x\cos^2x+\cos^6x\sin^2x=-\sin^4x\cos^2x+\sin^2x\cos^4 x.$$

Divide by $\sin^2x\cos^2x$ to get

$$-\sin^4x+\cos^4x=-\sin^2x+\cos^2 x.$$

This leads to

$$(\cos^2x-\sin^2x)(\cos^2x+\sin^2x)=-\sin^2x+\cos^2 x.$$

But since $\sin^2x+\cos^2x = 1$, we have equality. You will have to be careful when dividing though since we cannot divide by zero, so you may have to prove those situations as a special cases.

Comment: Thanks! I uopvoted, but because I made the account recently it might not show.